# Multitasking functions in swift

Tags: swift, multithreading, multicore, multitasking

I am making a game that involves loading chunks as a player walks to the left or right, however, the current framework I have for loading chunks involves a large for-loop. The issue is whenever a chunk is loaded, the game hiccups for a second while running through that list. Is there a way to push this function to the background, so it can run, and the main game doesn't have to stall while it waits for it to finish!

If there any other form of simultaneously running code blocks or functions in swift I would be happy to try to adopt them into my game. I am very new to multithreading and multicore work, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're developing for Apple platforms, you should look into GCD (Grand Central Dispatch). Swift doesn't  yet have native concurrency support. (It's in plan, but hasn't been added to the lanugage)

The idea is that you'd submit a block to a background dispatch queue for your "heavy lifting" data processing. In that block you'd loop through your data and then use `DispatchQueue.main.async {<code>}` to send your data to the main thread for display (UIKit code should never be executed from a background thread.)